# Benevolency required

Tags: support, reputation

I volunteer for a community health website, and I need to ask a question by posting a comment [on this thread, after the 2nd question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26962/3206).

My question would be:

> "Where is this function "get_my_thumbnail" inserted?"
>
> Is it inserted inside single.php? etc?
>
> Please be as explicit as possible.

Would anyone be willing to:

- Provide my account with +5 rep
- Post the question on my behalf
- Add a comment after the answer, which answers my question.
- Answer the original thread's question, with an updated answer.

Thanks.
Steve.

Answer (score 15):

> Provide my account with +5 rep

No, why would anyone do that. You have asked 119 question, with a huge amount of them wit no accepted answers or any type of feedback. Me for one remember a time where I let you email me your theme, corrected the errors for you, mailed it back and then **NEVER** received any feedback from you again, you also point blank refuse to accept my answer. So, why would I help you again, and why would anyone who helped you in the past help you again.

We all spend our free time helping others, and frankly, people like you is on my list of never help again, and believe me, I think you are not just on my never-help again list. This is a community of give and take, not just take and take and take

FYI, by simply accepting answers which helped you solve your issue  gains you **2 REPUTATION** point, so accepting three of the ton of non accepted answers will gain you **6** rep points.

Also, if you really need extra reputation, start by actually getting involved in the site. Do some constructive edits, and accepted suggested edit gains you **2** reputation points. Again, 3 accepted suggested edits gain you **6** reputation points

> Post the question on my behalf

Post your own question. I do not see why someone else must post a question on your behalf when you are perfectly capable of doing it yourself

> Add a comment after the answer, which answers my question.

Again no, valuable info should never be posted as comments.

> Answer the original thread's question, with an updated answer.

Again no, I have more important things to attend to than trying to help someone with such a crappy attitude. I told you this before, if you really want help, you should start by changing your crappy attitude towards others that are still willing to help you.